# Advice Needed: How to properly connect React to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I have been investing some time learning React, MongoDB, and other JS web app related tools. For a small project that I created, I am using this repository to create my toy app [Create React App with no build](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). As I've progressed through my app I've learned a lot of React related tools and materials after the fact.

The part that I am stuck on is I am trying to submit a contact form's data into MongoDB but so far I'm unsuccessful in hooking up my app with MongoDB.

Here is my code for MongoDB. I've pretty much copy and pasted the code from the MongoDB guides onto my web app into a `src/modules/mongo.js` file

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/danielrubio';

const insertFormData(db, callback) {
   db.collection('contactsubmissions').insertOne( {
      "name": name,
      "message": message,
      "email": email
    }, function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Inserted a document into the restaurants collection.");
    callback();
  });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  insertDocument(db, function() {
    db.close();
  });
})
```

The above code is straightforward, it basically inserts one document into a collection.

Here is my second file in `src/modules/contact.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Formsy from 'formsy-react';
import { FormsyText } from 'formsy-material-ui/lib';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import '../assets/css/style.css';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  handleSubmit(data) {
    db.insertDocument({
       form submission info
       db.close()
    })
  }

  ......more code.....

  }
```

Now so far, I've been able to work through the MongoDB guides, I've created my database, can access the console, and can insert data through the console. What I haven't figured out is how to wire my app to mongodb so when I click a submit button it will insert the document in the right database. Coming from Rails and using a little bit of Flask, I can usually call a `.create` method which connects to my database or do some sort of SQL Alchemy operation which opens and closes the database. I've tried this approach by attempting to combine the two files together but when I do that, I can't even run `npm start` otherwise I get these types of errors:

```
Error in ./~/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/drubio/Desktop/react_personal_website/node_modules/mongodb/lib/gridfs
 @ ./~/mongodb/lib/gridfs/grid_store.js 42:7-20

Error in ./~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'net' in /Users/drubio/Desktop/react_personal_website/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection
 @ ./~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js 5:10-24

Error in ./~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'tls' in /Users/drubio/Desktop/react_personal_website/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection
 @ ./~/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js 6:10-24
```

So my question is how can I simply connect my app to open the mongodb database and write to it? I've been reading a lot of tutorials but then I get rabbit holed and confused further talking about `Express`, `Mongoose`, `Flux` and on and on. From a high level overview it seems like I don't even need Express or Mongoose, I simply just want to insert my data without a schema and to be honest I don't really get what Flux is but from what I gather, I don't really need it for my small app (I think). I could use a little nudge in the right direction on this one. Thanks.

```
  [1]: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app
```

Comment: Are you attempting to bundle `MongoClient` (server code) with your React app (client code)?

Comment: @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson thanks for the reply. I don't know any other way. In Flask, you can use SQL ALchemy to call insert data into the database and then deploy to Heroku. I'm basically just trying to do the same with React and Mongo. Is bundling the server code and client code not the way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create endpoint (server side) can be Node can be something else like php, and there you will accept request and insert the data to your database. Your React app will make ajax call to the server and the server will put the data to the database

If you want to do that with express you can create simple express app with one route that will get the data from the client and will send that to MongoDB. you dont have to use Mongoose you can use MongoDB driver or outer to simply send the data to MongoDB.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Let me get your opinion on something. I am trying to understand how to do this and what I have found are these two links https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKwrOXl5TDI and https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/. Is either of them the correct way to do this. I really want to do the youtube video approach but it looks like it isn't compatible and the full stack react link says I need to host another server on another port. Is this how its typically done?

Comment: The explanation in the YouTube video I exactly what I told you and I think it's really simple to implement (client app talk to server app that talk to DB)

Comment: Thanks @Ariel I'll use that as my definitive guide then.