# React MongoDB MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect [TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function]

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

When I run "node testMongoDB.js" with the following code, I'm able to insert a row into my local Mongo database.  So this hopefully proves my database is installed, working and the connection string is correct.  I am able to see the data stored in the database after running it.
I'm doing a minimal "proof of concept" (no user security) to allow someone to upload a file, example a CSV (comma-separated value).  I will then parse it and store rows in the database.

But when I put the same code in a React application, and do "npm start", I get an error on the connection:

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
> first connect [TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function]

The full error is after the two code samples below.

testMongoDB.js code:

```
console.log("Test MongoDB Connect and InsertOne")

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const assert = require('assert')
const databaseUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/"
const databaseName = 'ShedCompanyPOC'
const collectionName = "filedata"

MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, function(err, db) {
   if (err) throw err; 
   var dbo = db.db(databaseName)
   console.log("About to try the insertOne")
   dbo.collection(collectionName).insertOne({
       Employeeid: 4,
       EmployeeName: "NewEmployee"
   })
   console.log("MongoDB InsertOne completed")
   process.exit()
 })
```

React code (app.js) [I have separately tested parsing the file and got that working, so next step was to store rows in database]:

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'  // use hooks 
import logo2 from './images/demo-logo.png';  // demo logo 
import './App.css'; 

function App() {
  // Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
  // const [files, setFiles] = useState([])
  const currDateTime1 = new Date().toISOString()
  console.warn(currDateTime1 + " Starting React/App: function App()")
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // Do something with the files 
    const currDateTime2 = new Date().toISOString()
    console.log(currDateTime2 + " trying to read file")
    acceptedFiles.forEach((file) => {
      const reader = new FileReader() 
      reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted')
      reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed')
      reader.onload = (data) => {
           // Do what you want with the file contents 
           //console.log("file size:", data.length);
           //const binaryStr = reader.result 
           //const fileContents = reader.readAsText
           const fileContents = data.target.result 
           const currDateTime3 = new Date().toISOString()
           console.log(currDateTime3 + " Text print of file contents:")
           console.log(fileContents)
           // get MongoDB all set up 
           const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
           const assert = require('assert')
           const databaseUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
           const databaseName = 'ShedCompanyPOC'
           const collectionName = "filedata"
           
           MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err; 
            var dbo = db.db(databaseName)
            console.log("About to try the insertOne")
            dbo.collection(collectionName).insertOne({
                Employeeid: 5,
                EmployeeName: "TestEmployee"
            })
            console.log("MongoDB InsertOne completed")
          })

           /*  This is what I really want to do when I get 
               the above easy MongoDB working 

           MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, function (err, dbClient) {
              console.log("First line of mongoClient")
              if (err) throw err; 
              var dbo = dbClient.db(databaseName)
              console.log("Connected successfully to MongoDB Server ")
              //const clientDb = client.db(databaseName)
              var bulkDb = dbo.collection(collectionName).initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
              // now process line by line 
              const lines = fileContents.split(/\r\n|\n/); 
              var linecount = 0 
              var line 
              for (line of lines) {
                    linecount++ 
                    console.log("Line=" + linecount + " Data=" + line )
                    bulkDb.insert({"line": line})
                }
              bulkDb.execute() 
              console.log("//End of file")
              dbClient.close()
          })
          */ 
          
        }
      reader.readAsText(file)
    })
  }, [])
  const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone ({onDrop}) 

  return (
    <div className="App" {...getRootProps()}>
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo2} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      </header>
      <input {...getInputProps()} />
      {
        isDragActive ? 
          <p>Drop the files here ...</p> : 
          <p>Drag and Drop a file here, or click to select files</p>
      }
      <p /><p /><p /><p /><p /><p />
      Thanks for using our company!
    </div>
    
      );
}

export default App;
```

The error in react (which is triggered when I drop a file on the web page).

```
error.js:36 Uncaught MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:67734:35)
    at Pool.emit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:38821:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57221:14
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57632:11
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:55228:7
    at callback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:55447:5)
    at makeConnection (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:55461:12)
    at connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:55226:3)
    at createConnection (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57621:3)
    at Pool.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57212:3)
    at Server.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:67797:15)
    at Server.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:84152:25)
    at createServer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:79102:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:79031:14
    at parseConnectionString (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:69648:3)
    at connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:78977:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77038:5
    at maybePromise (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:85970:3)
    at MongoClient.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77035:10)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77255:22)
    at FileReader.reader.onload (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:171:21)
```

Comment: Do you really need to connect React app to mongo directly? Initialize connection during the onLoad could be a problem. That connection should maintain whether or not you are querying.

Comment: As opposed to what, a rest service or something?  I need to store data in MongoDB.

Comment: This is insert-only, no query.

Comment: yes, simple node server which connects with mongo would do the job and your front end code would be more cleaner. I would not suggest connecting directly from front-end unless you are using firebase.

Comment: Ok, it's been a several months since I played with react; a lot to re-learn.   Was looking at this "todo-list" app, but it used Mongoose instead: https://www.devsurvival.com/todo-app-react-backend/  I have a MERN course on Udemy, but was trying to throw together a proof of concept by tomorrow.  

So for today, can I make it work like I started? Or not possible?

Comment: It was in the onload routine that I got the file parsed before I tried to add the MongoDB logic.  So it seemed like that's where I should put it.

Comment: It is possible. Actually it is nothing if you are not worried about authentication stuff. That mongoose is used in the node server not in the react.

Comment: No security on the Proof of Concept.  How can I make it work, you still haven't described what is causing the error.

Comment: I am passing a function to the connect:  MongoClient.connect(databaseUrl, function(err, db) {etc}

Comment: Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/40725411/2507725

Answer (score 1):

Here you are connecting with the database server inside the `onLoad` method. Ideally that DB connection should be initiated already and you are supposed to do the DB interaction. Creating new connections, again and again, is not recommended and that is not the ideal way to handle this. you simply can use simple node server and connect with DB through that. Your front-end code should be less heavy, cleaner and simple in order to do the proper rendering.

Comment: But can I make it work for a proof of concept.  What is the exact reason for the error?  I can go back and improve it later.

Comment: I'm using react-dropzone to drop a CSV file and parse it.  I'm basing my code on demos I saw on their site and other blogs.

Comment: I am not sure this way would work properly. I haven't test it. You can use `useEffect` hook to initiate the connection and consume it inside the rendering.